# Why does meta have two additional moderators?

Tags: bug, moderators, meta

I just noticed that there is a difference between [main](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) moderators list. Why is that?

Visual aids:

[image: main site moderators]

[image: meta site moderators]

Comment: See [this meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278823/262767) post for one of them. I don't know about the other. According to Adam Lear, "It should resolve itself over time" apparently.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi the other one is there since a longer time see another [meta.se post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277060/why-is-an-se-employee-suddenly-a-per-site-moderator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some oddities when accounts are merged and/or privileges removed for SE staff. Especially for metas it can take quite some time for this to get ironed out.

In more detail:

- One of the two (Kasra) is there since a longer time already. Due to some account merge he got mod privileges on numerous sites, and while this did get resolved the incorrect information is still cached on the per site metas (since seveal weeks). See [Why is an SE employee suddenly a per site moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277060/why-is-an-se-employee-suddenly-a-per-site-moderator)
- For the other one (Laura) the situation appears to be similar, although the cause is a different one. See the post mentioned by Najib [SE employee appearing on the mod list on every per-site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278823/se-employee-appearing-on-the-mod-list-on-every-per-site-meta)

Eventually both should disappear form the list again. When exactly is unclear though.

Comment: 6-8 weeks of course.